# FBshare - plugin com.apple.share.Facebook.post invalidated

Tags: objective-c, facebook, ios9, xcode7

Upgrade my app to support iOS9 via Xcode7,
I cannot share posts as I expect on facebook.

Here's how I share post:

```
FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"myURL"];
[FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self
                             withContent:content
                                delegate:nil];
```

And according to [FB docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9), I added something in info.plist:

[image]

Turned to my app (running on iOS9 device) to test sharing, I was not switched to facebook app but instead a sharing pop-up like `SLComposeViewController` showed up.

I got this error as I shared post via pop-up within my app:

> plugin com.apple.share.Facebook.post invalidated

Opened FB app myself and found my post was missing image and description from the shared url, but the url is valid and would direct me to the right page.

I hope my user would be switched to facebook app when they're sharing like it used to be and get reminder if they succeed with right image/description/link showing on post.
How can I fix this issue?

Comment: What version of the Facebook SDK are you using?

Comment: @BjörnKaiser the latest version recommended in FB documents.

Answer (score 0):

```
 FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
    content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://developers.facebook.com"];
FBSDKShareDialog *dialog=[[FBSDKShareDialog alloc]init];
dialog.mode=FBSDKShareDialogModeBrowser;
dialog.shareContent=content;
dialog.delegate=self;
dialog.fromViewController=self;
[dialog show];
```

> try this